# How do I assign a function to the 'Enter' button?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, enter, assign

I have written a program that will take in user input (name, surname and high school class) and when the user has finished typing they can press a button I have created called 'Enter'. However, to make my program a little neater I want the user to be able to use the enter key on the key board.

How do I assign the function currently linked to the 'Enter' button I have defined to the enter key on the keyboard so that the user can use either?

```
name_var = StringVar()
    def event_enter_1():
        self.Enter_1.config(state=(NORMAL if name_var.get() else DISABLED))

    name_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: event_enter_1())
    enter_name = Entry(self, textvariable=name_var)
    enter_name.pack()
    enter_name.focus_set()



    def enter_button_1():
        if len(name_var.get()) > 10 or any(l not in string.ascii_letters for l in name_var.get()):
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a real name.")
        else:
            global student_name
            student_name = name_var.get()
            self.Enter_1.config(state="disabled")

            self.display_surname= tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text = "Now please enter your surname.")
            self.display_surname.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

            surname_var = StringVar()
            def event_enter_2():
                self.Enter_2.config(state=(NORMAL if surname_var.get() else DISABLED))
            surname_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: event_enter_2())
            surname = Entry(self, textvariable=surname_var)
            surname.pack()
            surname.focus_set()

            def enter_button_2():
                if len(surname_var.get()) > 10 or any(l not in string.ascii_letters for l in surname_var.get()):
                    tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a real name.")
                else:
                    global student_surname
                    student_surname = surname_var.get()
                    self.Enter_2.config(state="disabled")

                    self.display_tutor = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text = "Now please enter your tutor group.")
                    self.display_tutor.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

                    tutor_var = StringVar()
                    def event_enter_3():
                        self.Enter_3.config(state=(NORMAL if tutor_var.get() else DISABLED))
                    tutor_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: event_enter_3())
                    tutor = Entry(self, textvariable=tutor_var)
                    tutor.pack()
                    tutor.focus_set()

                    def enter_button_3():
                        if tutor_var.get() not in ["5A1", "5A2", "5B1", "5B2", "5B3", "5C1", "5C2", "6A1", "6A2", "6B1", "6B2", "6C1", "6C2", "6C3"]:
                            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a tutor group that exists.")
                        else:
                            global student_tutor_group
                            student_tutor_group = tutor_var.get()
                            self.Enter_3.config(state="disabled")
                            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Details Confirmation", "Thank you for entering your details. Now you can begin the quiz. Good luck!")
                            parent.question_1.config(state="normal")
                            parent.enter_name.config(state="disabled")
                            self.destroy


                self.Enter_3 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=enter_button_3)
                self.Enter_3.pack()
                self.Enter_3.config(state="disabled") #Initially the enter button is disbabled as the user hasn't started typing


        self.Enter_2 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=enter_button_2)
        self.Enter_2.pack()
        self.Enter_2.config(state="disabled") #Initially the enter button is disbabled as the user hasn't started typing


    self.Enter_1 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=enter_button_1)
    self.Enter_1.pack()
    self.Enter_1.config(state="disabled") #Initially the enter button is disbabled as the user hasn't started typing
```

I do apologize if this in confusing, I am new to OO programming and so maybe there are more efficient ways. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a *binding* to connect an event to a function. In this case, the event is `<Return>`. You would do it like this:

```
enter_name.bind('<Return>', enter_button_1)
```

When the binding fires, it will call the function with one argument, which is an object describing the event. You'll need to modify your function to accept that event:

```
def enter_button_1(event=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I modify my function?